# Not able to get full url in php

Tags: php

I know this question has been already asked before but I couldn't find my solution.
If it possible can I get this url

```
https://fileflix.net/#file?getFile=2&title=test2&ftype=pdf&thumb=https%3A%2F%2Ffileflix.net%2Fapi%2F%3FgetThumb%26filePath%3D%2Ffiles%2Ftest%2Ftesttest21540699674%26s%3D300
```

in php? I've already tried $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```
echo '<script>console.log("url: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'")</script>';
```

and this is get logged to console

```
url: /
```

Please explain me if it is not possible.

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: echo '<script>console.log("url: '$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'")</script>';

Comment: Nothing after `#` is sent to the server, the hash is only for use by the browser.

Comment: I've also tried this. This get logged  "url: fileflix.net/". I want the full url.

Comment: You can't do it. It's not sent to the server.

Comment: Why do you need PHP? You can just use pure Javascript: `location.href`. It even includes all GET parameters and the hash portion of the URL.

Comment: (Actually, I guess you want to access the full URL on the server-side for some purpose. I only mentioned the JS way because you were using <script> tags to output the result, but I guess this was just for testing your output. Still I'll leave my comment here in case it's useful.)

Comment: I am adding open graph meta tag dynamically that's why I need php. When I am adding meta tags to head using javascript it not working. So I thought it would work if the page loaded with meta tags added by php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the hash in the wrong place in the URL. It needs to be after all the parameters that get sent to the server.

```
https://fileflix.net/?getFile=2&title=test2&ftype=pdf&thumb=https%3A%2F%2Ffileflix.net%2Fapi%2F%3FgetThumb%26filePath%3D%2Ffiles%2Ftest%2Ftesttest21540699674%26s%3D300#file
```

Your code will then print

```
/?getFile=2&title=test2&ftype=pdf&thumb=https%3A%2F%2Ffileflix.net%2Fapi%2F%3FgetThumb%26filePath%3D%2Ffiles%2Ftest%2Ftesttest21540699674%26s%3D300
```

To get the hostname you should print `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

You can't print `#file` in PHP because the hash is only used on the client, it's not sent to the server.